# Laravel 4, convert Blade syntax to PHP

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I would like to know what is the equivalent of:

```
@include('sidebars.pages')
```

In plain PHP?

I tried such things as:

```
<?php echo view('sidebars.pages'); ?>
<?php echo view('sidebars.pages')->render(); ?>
<?php echo render('sidebars.pages'); ?>
<?php Blade::compile_string("@include('sidebars.pages')"); ?>
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literally it's translated in to...

```php
<?php echo $__env->make('sidebar.pages', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>
```

So out of your list of attempts, nearest might be

```php
<?php echo render('sidebar.pages', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path'))); ?>
```

---

Reference: [View\Compilers\BladeCompiler](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php#L274-L281)

```php
/**
 * Compile Blade include statements into valid PHP.
 *
 * @param  string  $value
 * @return string
 */
protected function compileIncludes($value)
{
    $pattern = $this->createOpenMatcher('include');

    $replace = '$1<?php echo $__env->make$2, array_except(get_defined_vars(), array(\'__data\', \'__path\')))->render(); ?>';

    return preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $value);
}

/**
 * Get the regular expression for a generic Blade function.
 *
 * @param  string  $function
 * @return string
 */
public function createOpenMatcher($function)
{
    return '/(?<!\w)(\s*)@'.$function.'(\s*\(.*)\)/';
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Sparks, I was really curious.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has already been answered but wouldn't the following also work?

```
<?php include 'app/views/yourview.php'; ?>
```